# Suggestion of a model for these type of data?

Tags: machine-learning, data, machine-learning-model, pca

I've got a data set that looks like this

```
physical_data1   physical_data2  switch1   switch2   state
400              500             1         0         Normal
400              500             1         1         Normal
500              650             0         0         Normal
600              700             1         0         Normal
1000             300             1         1         Anomaly!
```

where physical_data are data that are from 0 to 1000 and switch are switches that are binary (1 means on 0 means off).

I am still relatively new to machine-learning and so I am wondering what kind of machine-learning algorithm is best suited for these kinds of data to detect anomalies, where my data has mixed features of physical and binary quantities.

Things that i have done are, normalizing to [0,1], however i am not quite sure if applying PCA to this kind of data will result in a loss of detection rate because it requires all features to determine if a particular reading is normal or an anomaly.

One other question I have is that what if in my data set i do not have the Anomaly data, instead, only have normal data. In that case what kind of model can i use?

Answer (score 1):

Any kind of classification algorithm should be alright for your data.

Logistic Regression is probably the first thing you will learn in a ML tutorial.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

Answer (score 0):

Try [Naive bayes](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html). It's simple and can be used, if the features are independent of each others.